# Best way to return multiple values in echo from PHP and parsing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using ajax to request data and and echoing a string containing a number of variables and trying to parse this data using javascript.

`Echo eg. fullname=Joe Soap&companyname=banana&website=mywebsite.com`

In my javascript, I understand I could use string functions to search and extract, but this seems a bit cumbersome.

I'm assuming there is a much more elegant solution which I don't know about (I haven't been coding in PHP and javascript for very long) and I'm keen to learn the best practices.

**What is the best way to achieve this?**

1. Is this the best way to echo multiple values back to my javascript?
2. What is the best way in javascript to parse the data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is what JSON was designed to do.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: The second answer on the duplicate better explains the solution to what you ask. Long story short, you `echo` JSON, using PHP's `json_encode()` function, and then JavaScript can easily parse that.

Comment: JSON worked perfectly here thanks! Always good to learn something new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need json_encode

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Perfect thanks, thats the push in the right direction I needed. Used json_encode on my php side and JSON.parse on my javascript side.